# What are the chances of getting exactly the same object reference twice

Tags: java

I sometimes assume that if `oldObject != newObject` then the object has changed - which seems a fair assumption in most cases but is it truly a bad assumption?

In short, under what situation could the following code print "Same!"?

```
static WeakReference<Object> oldO = null;
...

Object o = new Object();
oldO = new WeakReference(o);

// Do some stuff with o - could take hours or even days to complete.
...

// Discard o (or let it go out of scope).
o = null;

// More stuff - could be hours or days later.
...
o = new Object();

// Later still.
if ( o == oldO.get() ) {
  System.out.println("Same!");
}
```

I realise that this is indeed remotely possible because an object reference is essentially the memory address of the object (or could be in some JVM). But how likely is it? Are we talking decades of run-time before it actually happens?

**Added**

My apologies - please assume that `oldO` is some form of `weak` reference that does not stop it from being collected. Perhaps it is `Weak` as the code (now) suggests or the reference is store in a database or a file somewhere.

Comment: If you could write down the address of the first object and then discard it, then it would be possible for the new object to be located at the same address ... and I guess this could happen any time then.

Comment: "then the object has changed" I trust by this you mean "has been destroyed and a new one put in its place".

Comment: Apologies - I meant (as @Ridcully suggests) that the `oldO` does not hold the object from being released.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon: oldO is an instance of WeakReference, while O is an instance of Object, both of which are still alive and well (although the object referred to by oldO may have been collected), so the answer is trivial: never.

Comment: The only way they can be the same if they both point to `null`, really. Either way you should really be using an equality method rather than ==, and the == isn't really useful in the equality method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I'm answering what I think what you really wanted to know, rather than the particular snippet you have)

It's implementation dependant. The contract of object reference is that as long as the object is still alive, no other object will compare == with it. This implies that after the object is garbage collected, the VM is free to reuse the same object reference.

Implementation of Java may choose to use an increasing integer for object reference, in which case you can only get the same object reference when the reference counter overflows back to 0. Other implementation may use memory location, which makes it more likely for the same reference to be reused. In any case, you should define your own object identity if that matters.

Comment: Thank you - are you therefore saying that it is JVM dependant? If so what are the chances given each of the mechanisms you mention? Likely? Small? Vanishingly small? I stress that it is for the **same** object.

Answer (score 4):

never will it be the same. oldO will always reference the initial object so it will never be discarded and new object can't have same address.

UPDATE: seems like answer was updated to specify that `oldO` is a weak reference.  In this case, when the object goes away, `oldO`'s reference will become null. This means it will never match another object in the JVM.

Comment: New object can't have the same address? Isn't the purpose of garbage collection to free up memory so that that same memory can be re-used by other objects?

Comment: @Adrian, the old object will never be garbagecollected because it is always referenced by the variable `oldO`. And if you reset `oldO`, then you never know what it pointed at initially. btw JVM can move your object around during runtime so you are not guaranteed `oldO` is always the same (i.e. address in phisical/virtual memory of the object can change at any time).

Comment: That's not true, because oldO is a WeakReference.

Comment: @Adrian, ahm you are right. In this case, when objectr goes away, `oldO` reference will become null. This means it will never match another object in the JVM. Was it weak when question was asked initially?

Comment: Looks like it was updated to specify WeakReference -- I didn't see the original post but it looks like most answers had the same impression you did.

Comment: @akostadinov - It was changed - sorry. I added `oldO` last minute to demonstrate my point and it backfired.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible for them to be equal. You still have a reference to the old object (`oldO`), so it will never be discarded.

Comment: A WeakReference isn't the same as a normal reference - the entire point is that it allows the object referred to to be garbage collected.

Comment: This answer was written before the author added to the question.

Comment: Fair enough - answer should be amended or deleted then.

Comment: didn't realize the question changed until just now. I will try and amend it when I get some more time.

Comment: My apologies ColinD - I messed up the question initially and had to change it.

Answer (score 1):

`o == oldO` means `o`is the same memory address as `oldO`. So, that cannot happen unless, at some time, you are doing either `o = oldO` or `oldO = o`. By transitivity, doing `foo = o; oldO = foo` or anything equivalent will achieve the same result, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, memory address is irrelevant. Java ain't C. Object identity is a JVM implemention - it may, or may not, rely on memory address, but more likely does not, since the JVM is free to move the object around in memory but must maintain its identity.

But regardless. because you hold a reference to the original object, the second one can not be the "same" object.

Comment: They hold a *weak* reference to the original object. That's a very important distinction in this case, and is the whole point of OP's question.

Comment: @Adrian the question was edited *after* I answered. It doesn't change my answer though, because a weak reference would effectively be null if collected.

Comment: It certainly should change your answer: "because you hold a reference to the original object" is false.

Comment: @Adrian yes, but the reference is either held, or us null. Either way, it is not the "same" object; the test `o == oldO` will always be false, because `o == null` is false too.

Comment: The outcome is the same (and in the end the answer is correct) but the premise is wrong, is my point.

Answer (score 0):

It will never happen.

Your first object (`oldO`) is stored at a specific memory location.

Your second object will systematically be referenced at another memery location, as long as oldO is referenced.

So `oldO == o` will compare both memory addresses, which will always be different.

If you dereference oldO, it will be garbage collected, and you'll eventuelly be able to create a new object at this same address. But you won't be able to compare it with oldO, because it has been dereferenced.

Answer (score 0):

By having a reference to your old object, you prevent it being garbage collected, so you prevent that bit of memory being available for a new object, so they could never be equal.

I wondered if you used a SoftReference you could keep a reference to the old object, while allowing it to be garbage-collected BUT:

1) I *assume* once the old object is collected, the SoftReference is set to null and

2) this is artificially trying to force the situation, so doesn't really prove anything :-)

Answer (score 0):

[According to the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html), weak references will be cleared when the object is garbage collected. It does not specify what it means to be "cleared", but presumably it is set to null. If it is in fact set to null, null will never be declared == to any object reference, regardless of its memory location.